# How to fix Plugin.Iconize.FontAwesome.dll.so not found on a Xamarin Forms project?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism

I am trying to use Plugin.Iconize on a Xamarin.Forms with Prism app with Unity Container.

I added the following extensions to my solution and to my Android project :

1. Plugin.Iconize
2. Plugin.Iconize.FontAwesome

Also I followed the instructions here to initiate the plugin (https://github.com/jsmarcus/Iconize)

when I deploy the app to an emulator i get the following erros on logcat:

Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
03-23 02:56:46.706  Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo    Debug   11975   Mono    AOT: image '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-x86_64-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/Plugin.Iconize.FontAwesome.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.companyname.PrismIconizeTest-x8vgXtp97tH1gQpbDIrahg==/lib/x86_64/libaot-Plugin.Iconize.FontAwesome.dll.so" not found

this is my XAML code :

```
            <iconize:IconImage
                HeightRequest="20"
                Icon="fas-address-book"
                IconColor="Blue"
                WidthRequest="20"
                BackgroundColor="Black"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not a direct answer to your problem, but in case you didn't know: you don't need to use a plugin for font icons anymore. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts#display-font-icons

With Xamarin.Forms 3.6 you can use a `FontImageSource` to display a font icon. Your app will be a bit smaller when using built in techniques.

```
<Image BackgroundColor="#D1D1D1">
    <Image.Source>
        <FontImageSource Glyph="&#xf556;"
                     FontFamily="{OnPlatform iOS=FontAwesome, Android=fontawesome.ttf#}"
                     Size="44" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: Thank you. I know about this, but I wanted to know why iconize does not work with prism. What I am doing wrong.